# Workfront API -> How to get all task id's associated to a project from workfront API?

Tags: workfront-api

I need to fetch all associated task ID's with a project from workfront API's.

I have a project id like: 1234567890
There are 18 task associated with this project.

My use case: I need to mark all those associated task to complete, for which I need the task ID's.

Note: If there is any other way to mark task complete in workfront, Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

Method Type: Get
Request: /attask/api/v9.0/search

Params:

1. projectID: 1234567890
2. apiKey :  (When using APIKey)

In Response, you will see all the task associated to that project.